# How do I create a google map inside an AngularJS component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I'm trying to create an AngularJS app for a demo that needs to use Google Maps.

I need to make the app AngularJS component based. The first problem I have come across is that I get an error when trying to create the map using:

```
 var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        streetViewControl: false
    }
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
```

Is this because it is using getElementById within the componenet controller? 
How do I do this?

What's the best practice for doing this with AngularJS components and GoogleMaps?

I have searched my training resources and not found anything that resolves this. I've also tried some ideas I found on StackOverflow but none resolved it.

I got some code via the GoogleMaps documentation, but that did not work and there was no explanation.

Essentially, I want a map on the left hand side of the webpage with several markers, and a 400px panel on the right. When clicked, the markers should show some of the data. The data is basically just an array of JavaScript objects (hard coded data for a demo, no data access to a web api or database involved). Within the right panel, there will be a header label that will just display the name property of the selected item. Below this there will be a list of the names of all the data items. When one of these is clicked, it should zoom to the relevant marker on the map. Below the list of names, there'll be a details panel. This will show the details of the selected item and should change whenever a new item is selected, either via clicking on the marker on the map, or by clicking on the name in the list.

So, these should all be components. But I've not been able to find how to communicate between the components. There's no need for any routing. It's almost a master-detail thing, but all the data is in the array of JavaScript objects.

Any help appreciated, as I've spent days digging, watching videos and trying things out to try to find how to do this but I've not really found anything that properly shows and explains how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good example here: https://embed.plnkr.co/RNyB3r5PMMpNgoxUZgX3/. Then you just have to do some style in html and change the locations.

Comment: Hi, that example is not using AngularJS components, though. It's there where I've run into a brickwall